# Python flask form

Tags: python, forms, sqlite, flask

maybe you can help me with following code / problem. I want to write a little tool with flask and sqlite to record my working time. It seems that I have troubles connecting the database although I was able to connect to database before. This the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///time-clock.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Project_Work(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    project = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=False, nullable=False)   
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=False, nullable=False)   
    date_start = db.Column(db.DateTime, unique=False, nullable=False)   
    date_end = db.Column(db.DateTime, unique=False, nullable=False)     
    time = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=False)            

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %r>' % self.id

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    tasks = Project_Work.query
    return render_template('index.html', tasks=tasks)


@app.route('/form', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def form():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        project = request.form['project']
        content = request.form['content']

        start = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.form['date_end'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        end = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.form['date_end'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        new_task = Project_Work(project=project, content=content, date_start = start, date_end = end, time = 8)

        try:
            db.session.add(new_task)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')

        except:
            return 'There was an issue adding your task'

    else:
        tasks = Project_Work.query
        return render_template('form.html', tasks=tasks)

@app.route('/delete/<int:id>')
def delete(id):
    task_to_delete = Project_Work.query.get_or_404(id)

    try:
        db.session.delete(task_to_delete)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/')
    except:
        return 'There was a problem deleting that task'

#Following function updates existings entries in the database by using the entry-id.

@app.route('/update/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update(id):
    task = Project_Work.query.get_or_404(id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        task.content = request.form['content']

        try:
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return 'There was an issue updating your task'

    else:
        return render_template('update.html', task=task)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I was able to create the database from the python terminal. When I put data manually into the database, I am able to read everything from the database. If I try to write data from the form into the database, the tool just redirects to the main page without writing the data into the database. It seems if the tool isn't connecting to the database. I don't get any error messages.

Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating database content on updating route with this

```
Project_Work.query.filter_by(id=id).update(
    dict(
        content=request.form["content"]
    )
)
db.session.commit()
```

instead of this

```
task.content = request.form['content']
```

Also it is good to check if the content isn't empty